# Как очистить определенные столбцы в выделенном диапозоне

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function Copy_Z() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Заказ'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:4').activate();
  var count = range.getNumRows();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), count);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  range.copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Выборка'), true);

Здесь должны очищаться столбцы  //spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
};
```

Как из выбранного диапазона очистить данные определенных столбцов?

Answer (score 0):

Не самый чистый код, но без хаков. Работает быстро

```
/**
 * Очищает колонки 'A', 'G', 'H', 'N', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' в диапазонах,
 * переданных в массиве
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} sheet
 * @param {Array.<GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Range>} ranges
 */
function clearing_(sheet, ranges) {
  var clmns = ['A', 'G', 'H', 'N', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
  var names = ranges.reduce(function(p, c) {
    var rS = c.getRow();
    var rE = c.getLastRow();
    var adr = clmns.map(function(clmn) {
      return [clmn, rS, ':', clmn, rE].join('');
    });
    p = p.concat(adr);
    return p;
  }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(names).clearContent();
}
```

Суть: необходимо создать `RangeList`, т.к. он не требует итераторов для обработки элементов, и очистить его. Самый "гибкий" способ создания такого списка - это создание на основе массива адресов.

Пример использования для вашего случая

```
function Copy_Z(){
  ...

  clearing_(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(), [spreadsheet.getActiveRange()]);
}
```

Можно передать список колонок как аргументы или вообще настроить функцию получения таких букв на основе алгоритма.